# Synchronized Tabbed navigation

Tags: jquery, css

I have two tabbed navigations, one on the top and one at the bottom.
I'm targeting the div through classes instead of id so that they both show relevant content.

When the user clicks the "Business" tab, it shows relevant information for the user, both on the top and on the bottom. My problem is that I cannot make both tabs to show the "active" state. It only shows on the tab that I clicked whether on the top or the bottom, although they have the same class name.

Any help is welcome.

Mike

---

HTML:

```
<!-- TOP TAB  -->
<section id="registerTabsContainer">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- TOP CONTENT  -->
    <div class="registerTabsContent tabViewer">
        <h1>Register as a Viewer</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabBusiness">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabPlatform">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- BOTTOM  TAB  -->
    <section id="tourSummaryTabsContainer">

        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- BOTTOM  CONTENT  -->
        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabViewer">
            <h1> Viewer content Bottom</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabBusiness">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabPlatform">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // tabs  script
    $('.tabs li a:first').addClass('active');
    $('.registerTabsContent:not(:first), .tourSummaryTabsContent:not(:first)').hide();

    $('.tabs li a').click(function() {
        var t = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.tabs li a').removeClass('active');     
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.registerTabsContent, .tourSummaryTabsContent').hide();
        $(t).fadeIn('slow');  

        return false;    
    })  
});
```

CSS:

```
.tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
}

.tabs li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    float:left;   
    list-style:none;
}
.tabs li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:13px;
    color:#999999; 
    padding:7px 25px 4px 25px; 
    display:block; 
    text-decoration:none;

    background: rgba(227,227,227,1);
    /*border-right: 1px solid rgba(153,153,153,1); */
}

.tabs li a.active {
    background: white;   
    color:#999999;
    /*border-top: 1px solid white;*/ 
}

.tabs li a:hover {
    padding:7px 25px 4px 25px;
    background:#fff; 
}
```

Comment: Why are you making an `inactive` class instead of an `active` class?

Comment: You are quite right! I'm editing the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have updated your code to use an active class as oppose to an inactive class.

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- TOP CONTENT  -->
    <div class="registerTabsContent tabViewer">
        <h1>Register as a Viewer</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabBusiness">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="registerTabsContent tabPlatform">
        <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- BOTTOM  TAB  -->
    <section id="tourSummaryTabsContainer">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href=".tabViewer">Are you a Viewer?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabBusiness">Are you a Business?</a></li>
            <li><a href=".tabPlatform">Are you a Platform?</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- BOTTOM  CONTENT  -->
        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabViewer">
            <h1> Viewer content Bottom</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabBusiness">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="tourSummaryTabsContent tabPlatform">
            <h1>Register as a Business</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
.tabs li {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

    .tabs li a {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #999999;
        padding: 7px 25px 4px 25px;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #e3e3e3;
        /*border-right: 1px solid rgba(153,153,153,1); */
    }

        .tabs li a.active, .tabs li a:hover{
            background: #fff;
            /*border-top: 1px solid white;*/
        }
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // tabs  script
    $('li:eq(0) a', '.tabs').addClass('active');
    $('.registerTabsContent:not(:first), .tourSummaryTabsContent:not(:first)').hide();

    $('.tabs li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $('a.active').removeClass('active');
            var i = $(this).parent().index();
            $('li:eq(' + i + ') a', '.tabs').addClass('active');

            $('.registerTabsContent, .tourSummaryTabsContent').hide();
            var t = $(this).attr('href');
            $(t).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });

});
```

Also, here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u5n92/). Please let me know if you need any explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works. just another thing, whenever I press the bottom tabs the window scrolls up a bit. I already tried using "prevent default" with no success.

Comment: I have updated my answer to now use `e.preventDefault();` in the click event. Is this how you are using it?